# Iterate through variable names in function

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

I have several countdowns on my page and I found this script below, that I have tried to modify to iterate through the original script in order for me to display several countdowns.

I for instance have a countdown in `<div id="dateHere1"></div>`, `<div id="dateHere2"></div>`, `<div id="dateHere3"></div>` etc...

That's why I need to iterate through the following function with numbers from 1 to 10. How can I add the string `str` (which is 10) to variable names in my function?

```js
var str = 10;

for (i = 0; i < str; i++) { 
    addEventsHereAndThere([i]);

}



function addEventsHereAndThere(number) {
// Set the date we're counting down to
var theCorrectDate.number = document.querySelector('#thisIsTheDate'.number).value;
var countDownDate.number = new Date(theCorrectDate.number).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x.number = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance.number = (countDownDate.number) - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days.number = Math.floor(distance.number / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours.number = Math.floor((distance.number % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes.number = Math.floor((distance.number % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds.number = Math.floor((distance.number % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
 if (days.number == 0 && hours.number == 0 && minutes.number == 0) {
  document.getElementById("dateHere".number).innerHTML = seconds.number + "s";
 } else if (days.number == 0 && hours.number == 0) {
  document.getElementById("dateHere".number).innerHTML = minutes.number + "m " + seconds.number+ "s";
 } else if (days.number == 0) {
  document.getElementById("dateHere".number).innerHTML = hours.number + "t "
     + minutes.number + "m " + seconds.number+ "s";
 } else {
    document.getElementById("dateHere".number).innerHTML = days.number+ "d " + hours.number + "t "
    + minutes.number + "m " + seconds.number + "s";
 }
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance.number < 0) {
        clearInterval(x.number);
  document.getElementById("dateBackgroundHere".number).style = "position:absolute; bottom:0; height:45px; width:100%; background: rgba(230, 47, 47, 0.8); color:#fff; font-family: Fira Sans, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 8px;";
        document.getElementById("dateHere".number).innerHTML = "UDLØBET";
    }
}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Do not rewrite existing question. Ask another one

Answer (score 0):

Two things jump out:

1. Don't wrap it in an array when passing it to the function:

   ```
   addEventsHereAndThere(i);
   // No [] here --------^
   ```
2. Use valid JavaScript (not PHP) string concatenation when using it:

   ```
   ... = document.querySelector('#thisIsTheDate' + number).value;
   // + not . here ------------------------------^
   ```

---

Side note: When selecting an element by just its ID, you're better off using `getElementById` (without the `#` since it takes an ID, not a selector) than `querySelector`, so:

```
... = document.getElementById('thisIsTheDate' + number).value;
```

They'll end up with the same result, but `getElementById` is much, much faster. (Not that it's likely to really matter often.)

Comment: So, how do I iterate through the variable names in the function?

Comment: @M.Pedersen: What do you mean? What variables?

Comment: I have edited my question as the problem was in another part of my code. Hope you can help me!